# spring-data-elasticsearch support for elasticsearch version 7.14

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

ElasticsearchRestTemplate uses import org.elasticsearch.common.unit.TimeValue;. However in latest elasticsearch version 7.14 this class does not exist. Using ElasticsearchRestTemplate.searchScrollStart method results in a NoClassDefFound Exception.

Which version of spring-data-elasticsearch will support the version 7.14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest milestone version 4.3.0-M2 uses 7.13.3 (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.3.0-M2/reference/html/#preface.versions).

I can't tell yet if we upgrade to 7.14 before M3 - and therefore before 4.3.0  GA

**Edit 18.09.2021:**

Client libraries 7.14.1 are included now from 4.3.0.M3 on that has been released last Friday.

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. This enables me to move to the latest version for elastic search

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.elasticsearch.common.unit.TimeValue;
```

should be replaced by:

```
import org.elasticsearch.core.TimeValue;
```